# import string in ArrayList using buffered reader

Tags: java, arraylist, static, bufferedreader

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordList{

   private static ArrayList<String> words;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
String line;

BufferedReader br = null; 

        try {
          line = null; 
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filename"));

            while (( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            ArrayList.add(line);// error
            }
        }

            catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

finally {
   try {
    if (line == null)br.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
}
}
```

I'm trying to add string from a txt file to an arraylist by using bufferedReader. I'm not sure how to proceed. I tried this line
ArrayList.add(line);
but it does not work. error: Can not be referenced from a static context, non-static method add (E).
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At first, you need to initialize `ArrayList` to avoid NPE.

```
   private static ArrayList<String> words=new ArrayList<>();
```

Use `ArrayList` identifier name `words` for add data.

```
    words.add(line);// Use identifier words
```

Answer (score 0):

initialise array list like

`words=new ArrayList<String> () ;`

ans then call `words.add(line);`